# How to format PHP Json array for Angular scope via Ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, ajax

So I am trying to avoid the php while loop to fetch data from Mysql and print out the result with html tag for my ajax query. It makes my Ajax query heavy for nothing.

The first thing that came to my mind was to send MySQL result array straight back to javascript that could update an Angular scope. So all the html is already on client side and agular will repeat it depending on the received data.

I will start with what i think is not working in my code but evry thing will be added just after;

In PHP ;

```
$data = array();
$data[0] = 'OK';  // status from server OK/ERROR
$data[1] = '{id: 1, name: "a name", cote: "10.5", style: "jungle", centre: "supercentre", img: "x"},
{id: 2, name: "ma nouvelle route angulaire2", cote: "10.5", style: "jungle", centre: "supercentre", img: "x"},
{id: 3, name: "ma nouvelle route angulaire3", cote: "10.5", style: "jungle", centre: "supercentre", img: "x"}';  


header("content-type:application/json");
echo json_encode($data);
```

Now I am just trying to figure it out but eventualy my goal would be to pass Mysql result to the data[1];

After that back into javascript to update the angular scope. Be advise that this part of code is not within the main angular app but in my javascript promise function that deals with all the ajax request.

```
   var scope = angular.element($("#object_container")).scope();
        scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.objects = data[1];
    });
```

I can see the content of data[1] in the console. But the scope is not displaying it. I think Angular is not liking the way im formating my array.

I have also tryed

```
$data = array();
$data[0] = 'OK';  // status from server OK/ERROR
$data[1][0] = '{id: 1, name: "ma nouvelle route angulaire1", cote: "10.5", style: "jungle", centre: "supercentre", img: "x"}';
$data[1][1] = '{id: 2, name: "ma nouvelle route angulaire2", cote: "10.5", style: "jungle", centre: "supercentre", img: "x"}';
$data[1][2] = '{id: 3, name: "ma nouvelle route angulaire3", cote: "10.5", style: "jungle", centre: "supercentre", img: "x"}';  


header("content-type:application/json");
echo json_encode($data);
```

The console;

This is the entire data array from php

```
(2) ["OK", Array(3)]    

The scope before update

ajax-process.js:71 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]   


And the scope after update

ajax-process.js:73 (3) ["{id: 1, name: "ma nouvelle route angulaire1", cote…style: "jungle", centre: "supercentre", img: "x"}", "{id: 2, name: "ma nouvelle route angulaire2", cote…style: "jungle", centre: "supercentre", img: "x"}", "{id: 3, name: "ma nouvelle route angulaire3", cote…style: "jungle", centre: "supercentre", img: "x"}"]
```

**UPDATE**
This is giving me the right output but my page is not updated with the new scope values.

```
$data = array();
$data[0] = "OK";  // status from server OK/ERROR
$data[1][0]->id = "1";
$data[1][0]->name = "route Angulaire";
$data[1][0]->cote = "10.5";
$data[1][0]->style = "jungle";
$data[1][0]->centre = "some center";
```

Comment: while creating array in php "At position [1][0], [1][1], [1][2]" make it json decode first than assign inside php array

Comment: Your JSON string isn't valid JSON. The property names should be wrapped in `""` double quotes.

Comment: The last update is giving me the right data format but still not changing the page content